# Attaching one persistent disk to each of my multiple instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

How would I attach one disk to each of my compute instances? My current code is shown below.

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "compute-node" {
  count = "${var.node_count}"
  name         = "attached-disk-instance-${count.index}"
  machine_type = "e2-medium"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }

  attached_disk {
    source = google_compute_disk.compute-disk[count.index].self_link
  }
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "compute-disk" {
  count = "{var.node_count}"
  name  = "test-disk-${count.index}"
}

resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "attached-disk" {
  count = "${var.node_count}" 
  disk     = google_compute_disk.compute-disk[count.index].id
  instance = google_compute_instance.compute-node[count.index].id
}
```

From this, I get a "resourceInUseByAnotherResource" error because one of my disks that is already in use by another instance is trying to be attached to a new instance. This is what it looks like:

```
Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 400: The disk resource 'projects/project_name/zones/us-central1-c/disks/compute-disk-0' is already being used by 'projects/project_name/zones/us-central1-c/instances/compute-instance-0', resourceInUseByAnotherResource
│
```

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Have you changed the code that gives that error? I'd expect the code in the question to complain about your use of `google_compute_instance.compute-node.id` when `google_compute_instance.compute-node` is using `count`. Could you please make sure that your question includes the code that produces the exact error (ideally as a [mcve]) and then also include the full error with the context surrounding it (eg the resource name)?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will fix this

Comment: Why are you trying to attach it with both the `google_compute_instance` `attached_disk` parameter and also the `google_compute_attached_disk` resource? You only need one of these.

Comment: Which one should I remove?

Comment: Either one is fine. I'd probably remove the `google_compute_attached_disk` resource unless you have a need for separating it out into a separate resource. Some things are made easier by having a separate resource (and pre 0.12 and dynamic blocks you wouldn't have been able to dynamically attach a varying amount of disks to an instance without it) but your goal should be achievable just with the `attached_disk` parameter.

Comment: This link should help you. To attach a disk in multi-writer mode, requires N2 instances (max 2 instances) https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/sharing-disks-between-vms 2) Else the disk must be attached read-only.  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/sharing-disks-between-vms#use-multi-instances